# Use aggregateBykey or reduceByKey to get aggregated records for a key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate, rdd, apache-spark-2.0

I have the input data of the format

```
RDD[
(Map1, RecordA),
(Map2, RecordX),
(Map1, RecordB),
(Map2, RecordY),
(Map1, RecordC),
(Map2, RecordZ)
]
```

Expected out format is (List of RDDs) :

```
List[
RDD[RecordA, RecordB, RecordC],
RDD[RecordX, RecordY, RecordZ]
]
```

I want the inner RDDs to be grouped by the key that is Map1, Map2 and I want to create a outter List as a collection of inner RDDs.

I tried using reduceByKey API and aggregateByKey API and have not been successful so far!

Real World example :

```
RDD[
(Map("a"->"xyz", "b"->"per"), CustomRecord("test1", 1, "abc")),
(Map("a"->"xyz", "b"->"per"), CustomRecord("test2", 1, "xyz")),
(Map("a"->"xyz", "b"->"lmm"), CustomRecord("test3", 1, "blah")),
(Map("a"->"xyz", "b"->"lmm"), CustomRecord("test4", 1, "blah"))
]

final case class CustomRecord(
string1: String,
int1: Int,
string2: String)
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can't create RDD of RDD; Maybe RDD of Lists or Iterables?

Comment: List[
RDD[RecordA, RecordB, RecordC],
RDD[RecordX, RecordY, RecordZ]
] is also acceptable.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Can you give a real example instead of a schema?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580350/2204206

Comment: @Psidom Done. I updated the question with my  data. key is a Map[String, String] and value is a CustomRecord.

Comment: @LiorChaga I don't want a List[List[], List[]] I was able to achieve this with aggregateByKey. I need List[RDD[], RDD[]] .

Comment: you can't do that directly in spark. You can take the List<List>>, iterate over the outer list and use sc.parallelize to convert the inner list to RDD, then collect back to List to get what you want.
Or - you can take the original RDD, collect the keys, and then iterate over keys. For each key, map the original rdd to get an rdd of values for that key, and just add those rdds one by one to a list...

Comment: I tried doing that I am running into the org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext. So I was wondering if I could directly convert it to RDD

Comment: spark functions should be serializable, as well as any constructor args you are passing them. You can post code snippet and I guess someone would spot the problem right away (I'm less of a scala person myself)