# ReduceByKey method for aggregating dictionaries

Tags: python, pyspark, reduce, flatmap

I've got a spark method where I'm running a `flatMap` function which is returning me a list of tuples. The key value in the tuple is a `Timestamp`, and the value is a `dict`.

```
[(Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
  {'id': '1', 'val': '200M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
  {'id': '2', 'val': '10M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
  {'id': '3', 'val': '30M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'),
  {'id': '15', 'val': '120M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00')}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'),
  {'id': '3', 'val': '35M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00')}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'),
  {'id': '4', 'val': '56M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00')}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'),
  {'id': '6', 'val': '5M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00')}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'),
  {'id': '1', 'val': '25M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00')}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'),
  {'id': '2', 'val': '7M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00')}),
```

I'm trying to run a `reduceByKey` function next which gives me:

```
[ (Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
  [{'id': '1', 'val': '200M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')},
   {'id': '2', 'val': '10M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')},
   {'id': '3', 'val': '30M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')}]),
  (Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'),
  [{'id': '15', 'val': '120M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00')},
   {'id': '3', 'val': '35M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00')},
   {'id': '4', 'val': '56M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00')}]),
  (Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'),
  [{'id': '6', 'val': '5M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00')},
   {'id': '1', 'val': '25M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00')},
   {'id': '2', 'val': '7M', 'date':Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00')}]) ]
```

So far I've tried this: 
`output = rdd.flatMap(split_func).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y).collect()`

but I get this error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is more a python error. If `d1` and `d2` are dictionaries then `d1 + d2` does not work. However, you can do `{**d1, **d2}`. If d1 and d2 have the same key it will take the value from d2.

So you could do `output = rdd.flatMap(split_func).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: {**x, **y}).collect()`

However, you result is a list of tuples. So in this case I think groupByKey is better: `output = rdd.flatMap(split_func).groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect()`

Comment: that doesn't actually seem to work - it seems to just give me the first `dict` of each key:
`[(Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'), {'date': Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00'), 'id': '2', 'val': '7M'}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'), {'date': Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00'), 'id': '15', 'val': '120M'}),
 (Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), {'date': Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'), 'id': '1', 'val': '200M'})]`

Comment: ah ok. This is because they are tuples. In that case your best bet would be groupByKey: https://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-groupbykey-example/

Comment: I wanted to avoid using `groupByKey` since it returns an iterable.. I'd rather have a large list of dicts.. (is it possible?)

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can change the iterable to a list by adding a `mapValues(list)` before the collect. But I really think your only option is groupByKey unless you want to write a massive UDF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580303/using-reducebykey-to-group-list-of-values