# How to filter RDDs using count of keys in a map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following RDD

```
val reducedListOfCalls: RDD[(String, List[Row])]
```

The RDDs are:

```
[(923066800846, List[2016072211,1,923066800846])]

[(923027659472, List[2016072211,1,92328880275]),
  923027659472, List[2016072211,1,92324440275])]

[(923027659475, List[2016072211,1,92328880275]),
 (923027659475, List[2016072211,1,92324430275]),
 (923027659475, List[2016072211,1,92334340275])]
```

As shown above first RDD has 1 (key,value) pair, second has 2, and third has 3 pairs.

I want to remove all RDDs that has less than 2 key-value pairs. The result RDD expected is:

```
[(923027659472, List[2016072211,1,92328880275]),
  923027659472, List[2016072211,1,92324440275])]

[(923027659475, List[2016072211,1,92328880275]),
 (923027659475, List[2016072211,1,92324430275]),
 (923027659475, List[2016072211,1,92334340275])]
```

I have tried the following:

```
val reducedListOfCalls = listOfMappedCalls.filter(f => f._1.size >1)
```

but it still given the original list only. The filter seems to have not made any difference.

Is it possible to count the number of keys in a mapped RDD, and then filter based on the count of keys?

Comment: In your example you have shown List which contains same elements for identical keys. Have you tried reducebykey?

Comment: The keys are the same, but the values are different as you can see. I need all values, when the number of keys > 1, reduceByKey did not work for this

Comment: Are these all printings of the same RDD? It doesn't look like your `List[Row]` is the one holding these multiple tuples, it looks like the RDD simply has a different amount of tuples inside.

Comment: Why not just use `count`, i.e. `listOfMappedCalls.filter(_.count >= 2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aggregateByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#aggregateByKey(U,%20org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2,%20org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2)) in Spark to count the no of keys.

You should create a `Tuple2(count, List[List[Row]])` in your combine function. The same can be achieved by [reduceByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#reduceByKey(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2)).

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24805905/2784721) post comparing these two functions.