# Improve groupby operation in Spark 1.5.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

We are facing poor performance using Spark.

I have 2 specific questions:

1. When debugging we noticed that a few of the groupby operations done on Rdd are taking more time
2. Also a few of the stages are appearing twice, some finishing very quickly, some taking more time

Here is a screenshot of [image: Spark UI when running locally].

Currently running locally, having shuffle partitions set to 2 and number of partitions set to 5, data is around 1,00,000 records.

Speaking of groupby operation, we are grouping a dataframe (which is a result of several joins) based on two columns, and then applying a function to get some result.

```
       val groupedRows = rows.rdd.groupBy(row => (
        row.getAs[Long](Column1),
        row.getAs[Int](Column2)
        ))
      val rdd = groupedRows.values.map(Criteria)
```

Where Criteria is some function acted on the grouped resultant rows. Can we optimize this group by in any way?

Here is a screenshot of the [image: DAG Graph1].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to convert the existing `dataframe` to `rdd` and do the complex process you are performing.

If you want to perform `Criteria` function on two columns (`Column1` and `Column2`), you can do this directly on `dataframe`. Moreover, if your `Criteria` can be reduced to combination of inbuilt [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) then it would be great. But you can always use [`udf`](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-udfs.html) functions for custom rules.

What I would suggest you to do is `groupBy` on the `dataframe` and apply `aggregation` functions

```
rows.groupBy("Column1", "Column2").agg(Criteria function)
```

You can use [Window](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) functions if you want multiple rows from the grouped `dataframe`. more info [here](http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/spark-window-functions-for-dataframes.html)

Comment: I dont think Spark 1.5.2 `agg` operation take in a function, it just takes in inbuilt `sum`, `avg` etc functions. Criteria is something we run each record for the group and select a record.

After grouping we get `RDD[((Long, Int), Iterable[Row])]` and for each (key, key) we get a seq of rows, which we give it to Criteria

Comment: For that you should have a look at udaf aggregations. UDAF seems to be appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

`.groupBy` [is known](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#groupBy(scala.Function1,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) to be not the most efficient approach:

> Note: This operation may be very expensive. If you are grouping in
>   order to perform an aggregation (such as a sum or average) over each
>   key, using PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey or
>   PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey will provide much better performance.

Sometimes it is better to use `.reduceByKey` or `.aggregateByKey`, as explained [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html):

> While both of these functions will produce the correct answer, the
>   reduceByKey example works much better on a large dataset. That's
>   because Spark knows it can combine output with a common key on each
>   partition before shuffling the data.

Why `.reduceByKey`, `.aggregateByKey` work faster than `.groupBy`? Because part of the aggregation happens during `map` phase and less data is shuffled around worker nodes during `reduce` phase. Here is a good explanation on [how does aggregateByKey work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804619/how-does-spark-aggregate-function-aggregatebykey-work).

Comment: Thanks, replaced the groupby with aggregateByKey, seems much better now. But I still see duplicate stages getting executed again. You have any idea about it? I searched a lot in google but can't seem to get the answer.

Comment: I would advise to check the DAG of the execution and the Event timeline. From the image you posted it's hard to say. If you define RDD operations in a sub-function and call it twice, it may happen that some RDD actions appear in the timeline twice for different data.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I've added a part of DAG graph, since I can't upload more than 2 images.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you are running Spark 2, since Tungsten engine is new to Spark 2 (https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/23/apache-spark-as-a-compiler-joining-a-billion-rows-per-second-on-a-laptop.html). I assume what you call "appear twice" is about jobs 8, 9 and 10. Since I don't see the code, I assume that either there is a loop that generates those stages (=> they appear several times) or Tungsten engine optimizes it for you (and generates code somehow). I don't think I can provide more help here :) Good luck and have fun.