# Pyspark count distinct values of labels of a Labelled point RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have an RDD of [labeled point](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/mllib-data-types.html#labeled-point) in Spark. I want to count all the distinct values of labels. I try something

```python
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

train_data =  sc.parallelize([ LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]),LabeledPoint(2.0, [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]),LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]) ])

train_data.reduceByKey(lambda x : x.label).collect()
```

But I get

> TypeError: 'LabeledPoint' object is not iterable

I use Spark 2.1 and python 2.7. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data

Comment: @desertnaut I have update my question with some data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to convert your `LabeledPoint` to a key-value RDD, and then count by key:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.1.1'

from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

train_data =  sc.parallelize([ LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]),LabeledPoint(2.0, [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]),LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]) ])

dd = train_data.map(lambda x: (x.label, x.features)).countByKey()
dd
# {1.0: 2, 2.0: 1}
```

Comment: This solves the OP's pb. But it would be nice to have an explanation :)

Comment: Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804619/how-does-spark-aggregate-function-aggregatebykey-work and https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html you can add those links as extra reading :)