# Spark - difference between aggregateByKey() and reduceByKey()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to spark. Could somebody explain more detail about "aggregatByKey() lets you return result in different type than input value type while reduceByKey() return the same type as input".
If i use reduceByKey() i also can get a different type of value in output:

`>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,3),(2,3),(1,2),(2,5)])`

`>>> rdd.collect()`

`[(1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 5)]`

`>>> rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: str(x)+str(y)).collect()`

`[(2, '35'), (1, '32')]`

As we can see - input is int, output - str.
Eather i don't understand this diff correctly? whats the point?

Comment: `str(...)` accepts both `int` and `str` as input, which is why this works. Try with a function that returns a string but only accepts an int as input and it won't work.

Comment: Actually, I just tried `rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:str(x+0)+str(y+0)).collect()` and it produced `[(1, '32'), (2, '35')]` instead of crashing. I need to go meditate on the meaning of life now.

Comment: You can clarify your questions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804619/how-does-spark-aggregate-function-aggregatebykey-work) link.